slide two divs by clicking one link
I would like to implement this CSS-Only Carousel from this link: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XwbNwX. Instead of just one I would like two Carousel that are triggered at the same time by clicking one link. So for example, clicking the link1 would slide both cards with the number1. Example how should look like
I know that with bootstrap is easier but due to css and bootstrap conflicts in Wordpress I would like to keep only CSS. I am still a beginner.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.slides>div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.slides>div:target {
  /*   transform: scale(0.8); */
}

.slider>a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.slider>a:active {
  top: 1px;
}

.slider>a:focus {
  background: #000;
}


/* Don't need button navigation */

@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider>a {
    display: none;
  }
}

.slidecont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  justify-items: start;
}
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">5</a>
  <div class="slidecont">
    <div class="slides">
      <div id="slide-1">
        1
      </div>
      <div id="slide-2">
        2
      </div>
      <div id="slide-3">
        3
      </div>
      <div id="slide-4">
        4
      </div>
      <div id="slide-5">
        5
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slides">
      <div id="slide-10">
        1
      </div>
      <div id="slide-20">
        2
      </div>
      <div id="slide-30">
        3
      </div>
      <div id="slide-40">
        4
      </div>
      <div id="slide-50">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I have tried searching how i can href multiple ids with javascript/jquery but again without success. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]; links can break, rendering them useless to future readers.
